# Как сделать, чтобы *Сaption Lable* показывал сумму столбца `datagrid` c *ADOQuery*?

Tags: delphi

Как сделать, чтобы *Сaption Label* показывал сумму столбца `datagrid` c *ADOQuery*?

Comment: 1. Пройтись по набору, возвращенному `ADOQuery`, сложить все значения нужного поля в какую-либо переменную. 2. Вывести результат в `CaptionLabel.Caption`. Покажите свой код, который не отрабатывает правильно, чтобы вам могли дать более конкретные рекомендации.

Answer (score 1):

К вашему коду запроса добавить еще подсчет суммы необходимого столбца

```
SELECT SUM(имя_столбца) as 'summa1' FROM имя_таблицы;
```

А потом прочитать полученное значение:

```
ADOQuery1.FieldByName('summa1').AsString;
```